# Whole armature moves when one bone is moved

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

I made an armature and when I try moving the leg bone or the hand or the body it moves the whole armature and the other mesh with it. I even tried merging all the meshes together to see if it works, but it still does the same problem. I even tried with an un-merged mesh

Comment: Could you upload the .blend file to try to help you?